# Unable to set TaxonomyFieldValueCollection to SPListItem

Tags: 2013, splistitem, taxonomy

I have a taxonomy field which is muti-allow. I have placed a taxonomy picker control in the application page and the values which are entered in that control are to be set in the list.

My code is as follows:

```
private void SetFieldValues(SPListItem item)
{
    if (RadViewNewsOffices.Checked)
    {
        TaxonomyField officeField = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(FieldNames.Offices) as TaxonomyField;
        if (officeField != null)
        {
            TaxonomyFieldValueCollection selectedOffices = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(officeField);
            selectedOffices.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(twtcOffices.Text);
            officeField.SetFieldValue(item, selectedOffices);
        }
    }
}
```

I debugged the program and getting value at the line `officeField.SetFieldValue(item, selectedOffices);` that the method is not supported. The text which I am assigning through `twtcOffices.Text` looks something like:`Office 1|098400ee-334a-4b36-b690-a2b77330cc5d;Office 2|8deccb5f-0417-4773-8227-e2a48eae9153`.

What should I do to store the value in the taxonomy field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try like this:

`item[FieldNames.Offices] = selectedOffices;`